# Why my inner join query with != is not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have written a query to pick those records from table Works which also exists in WorkOrder table. That's cool but now I want to pick those records which exists in Works but not in WorkOrders.

I have written this query but this return wrong results.

```
Select w.NIT_No, w.WorkNo, wo.Amount, wo.Rate, wo.Quantity, wo.Unit, wo.ItemCode, wo.WorkOrderBoqID, 
wo.WorkOrderIssueDate from Works w
inner join WorkOrderBOQ wo
on w.WorkNo != wo.Work_No and w.NIT_No != wo.NIT_No
```

I have put != in ON.

Comment: I think this would never work. Try using LEFT JOIN to get expected results

Comment: If you want to compare two tables for the records why not go ahead with `EXCEPT` [except-operator-vs-not-in](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83684/except-operator-vs-not-in)

Comment: If you are hitting any `NULL` values, using `!=` won't give you the required result. Also, your query is pretty wack based on what you want to achieve. You just ain't going to find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It is *working*.  You are just expecting it to do something different.  It is producing every pair where the two values are different.

You probably intend:

```
Select w.NIT_No, w.WorkNo, wo.Amount, wo.Rate, wo.Quantity, wo.Unit, 
       wo.ItemCode, wo.WorkOrderBoqID, wo.WorkOrderIssueDate
from Works w left join
     WorkOrderBOQ wo
     on w.WorkNo = wo.Work_No and w.NIT_No = wo.NIT_No
where wo.WorkNo is null;
```

Note that selecting columns columns from `wo` doesn't really help anything, because they will all be `NULL`.  So, this logic is often written using `not exists`:

```
Select w.NIT_No, w.WorkNo
from Works w 
where not exists (select 1
                  from WorkOrderBOQ wo
                  where w.WorkNo = wo.Work_No and w.NIT_No = wo.NIT_Nowo.WorkNo
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a left join with Null entries from Right Table. Try this Query --

```
SELECT w.NIT_No
    ,w.WorkNo
    ,wo.Amount
    ,wo.Rate
    ,wo.Quantity
    ,wo.Unit
    ,wo.ItemCode
    ,wo.WorkOrderBoqID
    ,wo.WorkOrderIssueDate
FROM Works w
LEFT JOIN WorkOrderBOQ wo ON w.WorkNo = wo.Work_No
    AND w.NIT_No = wo.NIT_No
WHERE wo.Work_No IS NULL
    AND wo.NIT_No IS NULL
```